# Escrever um arquivo XML dentro da Solucion C#

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, importação

Boa noite Pessoal,

Gostaria de uma ajuda, a estrutura do meu projeto está de acordo com a imagem abaixo.

[image: Estrutura do Projeto]

Eu gostaria de importar os dados da minha tabela para esse arquivo 'arq.xml' que está dentro do projeto.

Estou tentando fazer com esse codigo:

```
     dt.WriteXml("arq.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
     MessageBox.Show("Dados Exportado com Sucesso");
```

Porém não está escrevendo, aí quando coloco o fullName de outro caminho, funciona. Porém queria salvar dentro do proprio projeto, para que o projeto tenha o proprio xml, sem ter nada externo, deu pra compreender?

Comment: dessa forma você vai escrever o arquivo na pasta em que estiver sendo executada a aplicação...muito provavelmente na pasta `debug`...  você pode pegar o xml da pasta debug, colocar na pasta da solution e adiciona-lo na solution, basta clicar no 8º icone da solution explorer, e depois em include... mas não faz muito sentido isso que você quer... talvez se explicar o proposito disso, poderemos ajudar de uma forma melhor

Comment: é para fins didático......, mas mesmo assim, nao entendi a tua abordagem, poderia me explicar melhor, por favor

Comment: você tem um DataTable, e quer exportar ele para um arquivo xml... quando vc executa o `dt.WriteXml("arq.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);` ele vai escrever o arquivo na pasta em que a aplicação está rodando... basta pegar o arquivo lá e colocar na pasta da solution. Tudo bem que é para fins didáticos, mas qual o objetivo de ter o `DataTable` em xml na pasta da solution ?